# cambio de valor de un input de texto en insert into table

Tags: php, mysql

El campo `compte` no se por qué tiene un limite máximo de `4294967295`. En cuanto le pones una cifra superior, p.e. `4294967296 o 9876543210`, en ese campo, el número mayor aceptado es el dicho al principio en cambio acepta cualquier otro inferior como `1234567890, etc.`

El código es este:

```
<input name="compte" size="10" maxlength="10" type="text" />
$compte = $_POST['compte'];
echo "<tr><td>Banko-konto / Compte bancari</td><td>$idAligxo $banc $oficina $dc $compte</td></tr>";
        $query = "INSERT INTO comptes_prv (id_aligxo, banc, oficina, dc, compte) VALUES ('$idAligxo', '$banc', '$oficina', '$dc', '$compte')";

.....
$query = "SELECT banc, oficina, dc, compte FROM comptes_prv WHERE id_aligxo = '$row[id]'";
...
$fila = mysql_fetch_array($rs);
echo "<br><tr><td><strong>Banko-konto / Compte bancari:</strong> $fila[banc] $fila[oficina] $fila[dc] $fila[compte]</td></tr>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

muy seguramente el campo compte es un `int(11)` para solucionar esto modifica tu base de datos y ponlo como un `bigint`, aceptara un numero de mayor cantidadde caracteres.